# Do not return any records if one value exist in a field?

Tags: sql

I have the following records:

```
ID  FIRST   LAST    CATEGORY
123 Tom     Smith   Teacher
123 Tom     Smith   Tutor
345 Julia   Brown   Banker
345 Julia   Brown   Tutor
567 Dan     Davids  Fireman
567 Dan     Davids  Golfer
567 Dan     Davids  Painter
```

I want to exclude all records that has 'Tutor' as a value.
My desired output would be this:

```
ID  FIRST   LAST    CATEGORY
567 Dan     Davids  Fireman
567 Dan     Davids  Golfer
567 Dan     Davids  Painter
```

How do I go about doing so?

The names come from the NAMES table and the categories comes from the CATEGORY table. The primary key is the ID field.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause! (Tip of today!)

Comment: Nope. Trying to find a way to exclude rows/records due to a certain value.

Comment: I'd say NOT EXISTS then.

Comment: I can use a WHERE category_cat NOT IN 'Tutor', but it'll return 'Teacher' and 'Banker'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, first, last, category FROM names WHERE
ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM names where category = 'Tutor')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was using a subquery with the category field (Category_cat) instead of the names ID field (Names_ID).

Answer (score 0):

Use a SELECT with a JOIN and a WHERE clause that excludes the 'Tutor' value.
You didn't describe your schema well enough for me to give an exact query, so you may have to change some naming, but this is the idea:

```
SELECT names.id, `first`, `last`, category 
FROM names JOIN category on names.category_fk = category.id
WHERE category.category != 'Tutor';
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions on table structure it would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
 [Name].[ID]
,[Name].[first]
,[Name].[Last]
,[Category].[Category]
FROM
 [Name]
INNER JOIN [Category]
ON [Category].[Category]
=  [Name].[Category]
AND [Category].[Category]<>'Tutor'
```